# R Pivot Table: count number of observations

Tags: r

How do you replace **mean** with **count** in the summariseExpression?

```
# Pivot Table
pt <- PivotTable$new()
pt$addData(df_long)
pt$addColumnDataGroups("year")
pt$addRowDataGroups("Indicator")             
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="TotalObs", summariseExpression="mean(value, na.rm=TRUE)")
pt$renderPivot()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to OS. Could you please explain a bit more and maybe add a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Also try substituting `mean()` by `n()`

Comment: Or `"length(na.omit(value))"`.